# Update comboBox when form Loads

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Hi to all I know that that kind of question been asked but it's not the same one,

In my case, i working with WinForms and Entity framework 6, have a data grid of some objects and when I double click on one of the rows I loading new window with all the information about the object,
In that window, i have couple of combo box that bound to the database and in the load process i can't update them with the value that I want, for example:

```
cbJobType.SelectedIndex = ActiveJob.JobTypesID;
```

in the load process that combo still has 0 items in it,

I think about doing some cache for storing the jobType information and load it from there

can you suggest a better way or the best practice for that kind of cases?

Thanks

Comment: Are you assigning the itemssource of the combobox when the new window opens? You will have load the itemssource of the combobox first and then only you can select a value, please check your loading logic where you set the itemssource of cbJobType.

Comment: In the Datasource property.

Comment: It impossible give you some useful tips - show code how you load data to the comboboxes and code how you open new window.

Comment: impossible? why, @David already did..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use properties.setting:

[image]

You can find the details in MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx), and to access the data in the settings, simply use:

```
YourCombo.ItemSource = Properties.Settings.Default.Paths; //just an example
```

Update: you can programatically update the source:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Paths.Add("First");
Properties.Settings.Default.Paths.Add("Second");
```

or you can loop the values obtained from database:

```
foreach(var someValue from someDataSource)
   Properties.Settings.Default.Paths.Add(someValue);
```

Comment: the values are taken from database and it's dynamic you can add or remove them

Comment: just need to initialize it before, Properties.Settings.Default.JobTypes = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();